# Using Lambdas to access a list in a list?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm a beginner trying to learn to use lambdas, 
I have the `class Character` who inside has a `"List<Item> inventory"`
which can hold `"class Sword: Item"` and `"class Shield: Item"`

I want to get a `List<float>` that displays the damage of each of my Characters.
The `damage` being the `sum of damages` of `items` in their `inventory(swords and shields)`.

So far i know i can do this to an individual character in my character list and get the sum of damage from his items.

```
float damage = characters[0].inventory.Select(item => item.damage).Sum(dmg => dmg);
```

But when i try to do all my characters at the same time this does not work.

```
List<float> charactersTotalDamagesFromEachCharacter = characters
            .Select(character => character.inventory)
            .Select(item => item)
            .Select(item => item.damage)
            .Sum(dmg => dmg);
```

I want to get a `List<float>` that represent the `characters total damages(sum of damage of their items)`.

Comment: hint: `.Select(item => item)` does noting. This can be simplified as: `characters.Select(character => character.inventory).Sum(item => item.damage);`

Comment: Start with realizing that `character` in your second query corresponds to `characters[0]` from the first, but for every item.

Comment: I cannot recommend enough to study Edulinq (http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/) to learn LINQ the smooth way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know total damage per each character you need to just sum the damage for each characters inventory (btw, you can sum directly without selecting the property to be summed and calling `Sum()` afterwards):

```
var totalDamagePerCharacter = characters.Select(c => new
{
    Character = c,
    TotalDamage = c.Inventory.Sum(item => item.Damage)
})
.ToList();
```

However, if you don't need to know the specific character that incurs the damage and you're only interested in having a list of total damages, just project the character to its total damage from the query above:

```
var listOfTotalDamages = characters.Select(
    c => c.Inventory.Sum(item => item.Damage)).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't see why is this upvoted. Neither helps OP to learn, nor answers his question `I want to get a list of floats that represent the characters total damages(sum of damage of their items).`

Comment: @IvanStoev, I've corrected my answer. Thanks for pointing out the error!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for individual damage, this should give you the correct result:-

```
List<float> charactersTotalDamagesFromEachCharacter = characters
                                           .Select(x => x.inventory.Sum(z => z.damage))
                                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!